# Android open document in Google Docs application using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-docs

I would like to open [Google docs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs) using intent from my application.

I already have a document in web (which has the permission "Anyone with the link can view").

I would like to add the document link in intent-data.

My objective is, on tapping a button Google docs application will open up displaying the document (no intent chooser dialog will be displayed)

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code it will not open intent Chooser dialoge

```
Intent markerIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
markerIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs"));
startActivity(markerIntent);
```

Comment: How to set the url of the document?